# How to restrict user to shop more than Gift card amount in Shopify Plus?

Tags: ruby, shopify

We are using Shopify plus platform and we have a requirement where a user issued a gift card amount $100 and he has the products in this cart more than $100 than if he applies the gift card it should not apply.

I have tried to find the applied gift card through cart object but it is not returning the gift card value.

Please suggest how we can achieve this.

Comment: Huh? This requirement sounds crazy.. Why wouldn't you just deduct $100 from the total price at checkout?

Comment: Can you show how you have "tried to find the applied gift card through cart object"? What code did you write? Can you provide a [mcve]?